# ember infinite scroll model with fixture data

Tags: ember.js, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement infinite scroll, found here: https://github.com/hhff/ember-infinity into my app but the instructions and examples are too sparse.

I am running Ember 2.5, and this seems to be old:

> "Inspired by @bantic's Ember Infinite Scroll repo, but without using
>   controllers, in preparation for Ember 2.0.

even though https://github.com/bantic/ember-infinite-scroll - which is deprecated - actually points here. So I don't know what's up with that.

Anyway, this is what my route looked like before:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import { users } from '../mirage/fixtures/config';

var usersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return users;
    }
});
export default usersRoute;
```

I'm not really sure what { users } means here. I guess it just wraps it in an object. It works, but I don't know how to interpret it with the infinite scroll add-on. According to its basic usage, it looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import InfinityRoute from "ember-infinity/mixins/route";

export default Ember.Route.extend(InfinityRoute, {
  model() {
    /* Load pages of the Product Model, starting from page 1, in groups of 12. */
    return this.infinityModel("product", { perPage: 12, startingPage: 1 });
  }
});
```

So I've naively tried to blend them together, like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { users } from '../mirage/fixtures/config';
import InfinityRoute from "ember-infinity/mixins/route";

var usersRoute = Ember.Route.extend(InfinityRoute, {
    model() {
        return this.infinityModel("user", { perPage: 12, startingPage: 1 });
    }
});
export default usersRoute;
```

This gives me the error:

***ember.debug.js:28556 Error while processing route: users.index No model was found for 'users' Error: No model was found for 'users'***

Obviously I'm not referencing users correctly. I tried removing the quotes around user but that just gives me a different error:

***ember.debug.js:28556 Error while processing route: users.index Assertion Failed: Passing classes to store methods has been removed. Please pass a dasherized string instead of {users: [object Object],[object Object] etc.***

This is my mirage/config:

export default function() {

```
    this.get('/users', function() {
        return {
            data: [{
                "id": 0,
                "details": {
                  "fname": "Jeanine",
                  "lname": "Sanford",
                  "phone": "(963) 535-2006",
                  "address": "646 Montauk Court",
                  "city": "Gratton",
                  "province": "ON",
                  "country": "Saint Vincent and The Grenadines",
                  "postalcode": "M8X1R1"
                }
              }, {
               // more users  
            }],
            meta: {
                total_pages: 5
            }
        };
    });
};
```

My model looks like this:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    fname: attr(),
    lname: attr(),
    phone: attr(),
    address: attr(),
    city: attr(),
    province: attr(),
    country: attr(),
    postalcode: attr()
});
```

EDIT: added file structure

```
app/
> controllers/
- > users/
- - - user.js
- - users.js
> mirage/
- > fixtures/
- - - data.js
- - config.js
> models/
- - user.js
> routes/
- > users/
- - - user.js
- - users.js
> templates/
- > users/
- - - user.hbs
- - application.hbs
- - users.hbs
- app.js
- index.html
- router.js
```

Comment: ¿Can you include the files path and name of the files you included? The only reason I think Ember can't find your model is because a bad file name. That would explain why the Mirage config were included in the route, because according to [Ember tutorial] (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/tutorial/ember-data/#toc_using-mirage-with-ember-data) that's not how Mirage is used, you just use the store and Mirage returns the configured mock data.

Comment: My file looks just like the files on the page (except the type property, which I removed once I concluded it was not being used). I will attempt to add my file structure to the OP.

Comment: I don't think ember-infinity works welll with fixtures. Basicly the `users` variable, required by `import { users } from '../mirage/fixtures/config';`, is already a array with users. Ember-infinity creates a JSON request to your backend. As far as I know, there is no option to load data from a variable. You could use a pretender though, see: http://hhff.github.io/ember-infinity/assets/dummy.js.